# Создать таблицу с данными без подключения к базе данных в Django

Tags: python, django

Возможно ли создать псевдомодель с данными в Django? Имеются данные, получаемые сторонними скриптами (всегда разные, хранить их не имеет смысла) и для корректного отображения на странице мне необходимо преобразовать эти данные в модель с этими самыми данными.
Нашёл в [документации](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels)  пример создания лишь модели, но без данных. Понимаю, что можно просто закинуть данные на страницу через контекст, но данный способ не подходит, поскольку используется сторонний модуль для рендера страничек, у которого входные данные именно модели.

Comment: А можно какие-нибудь подробности про этот сторонний модуль? Возможно, можно создать не саму модель, а что-то похожее на модель, которое сторонний модуль посчитает за настоящую модель)

Comment: Можно создать модель, просто не сохранять ее в базу. Тоесть без `create()` или `save()`. Пример: `obj = MyModel(title='title', **data)`. Единственное но - pk, а следовательно и id будут `None`

Comment: Используется модернизированный модуль [django material](http://forms.viewflow.io/). "Под капотом" всё настроено на отображение моделей для CRUD. Ко второму комментарию: а можно поподробней про Ваш способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлагаю всётаки использовать базу данных (хотяб `sqlite` в `/tmp/mini-shared-db.sqlite`) и вынести работу со скриптами в отдельную службу.

Использовать SIGUSR1 или другой сигнал (dbus?) для выполнения скрипта по требованию.

Этот сервис можно стартовать со всеми возможностями django используя [команды manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Запуск скриптов из обработчика django может вызвать ошибки связанные с блокировками файлов, устройств (или что там у вас за скриптами), с перезаписыванием промежуточных переменных и с прочей гонкой.

Comment: Было решено идти примерно по предложенному пути. Т.е. решили использовать в проекте таблицу базы данных в качестве кэша и обновлять в ней данные через скрипт по требованию на клиентской стороне. Осталось разобраться как это можно допилить с помощью celery, чтобы долгие команды на исполнение проходили в фоновом процессе